# Why redux store doesn't receive an update from immer

Tags: redux, react-hooks, immer.js

1. Combining reducers

```
export default (injectedReducers = {}) => {
  return combineReducers({
    ...injectedReducers,
    memoizedStamps: memoizedStampsReducer, // <-- need to write here
  });
};
```

2. Writing an action

```
const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  addStamp: (payload) =>
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_STAMP,
      payload,
    }),
});
```

3. Writing the reducer

```
export const initialState = [];

const memoizedStampsReducer = produce((draft, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case ADD_STAMP:
      draft.push(payload);
  }
}, initialState);

export default memoizedStampsReducer;
```

4. Using in a react hook

```
const useMemoizedStamps = () => {
  const [memStamps, dispatch] = useImmerReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const { addStamp } = mapDispatch(dispatch);

  useEffect(() => {
    addStamp({ body: 'body', coords: 'coords' });
  }, []);

  console.log(memStamps); // <-- gives [{ body: 'body', coords: 'coords' }] all good here
  
  return null;
};

export default useMemoizedStamps;
```

But it gets never saved into injected reducer "memoizedStamps". The array is always empty. It works perfectly will with connect(null, mapDispatchToProps), but can't use connect() in my custom hook.

What do I do wrong? What is the answer here?

--- UPD 1 ---
@phry, like so?

```
const useMemoizedStamps = (response = null, error = null) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [memStamps] = useImmerReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const { addStamp } = mapDispatch(dispatch);

  useEffect(() => {
    addStamp({ body: 'body', coords: 'coords' });
  }, []);

  console.log(memStamps);

  return null;
};
```

And now if I need them to be local, I need to use immer's dispatcher? Any way to merge these two dispatchers? P.S. this dispatcher really saved it to global state.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard useDispatch and useSelector hooks?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are using Redux here, only some weird version of `useReducer`, right? Why did you tag it `redux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading this, I think you just have a misconception.

Stuff is never "saved into a reducer". A reducer only manages how state changes.

In Redux, it would be "saved into the store", but for that you would have to actually use a store. `useImmerReducer` has nothing to do with Redux though - it is just a version of `useReducer`, which like `useState` just manages isolated component-local state with a reducer. This state will not be shared with other components.

If you want to use Redux (and use it with immer), please look into the official Redux Toolkit, which already comes with immer integrated. It is taught by [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Comment: I guess this is what I don't understand, how to save the state to the store? Because the current setup nicely saves to the store via wrapped component with connect(), but the state is local for this custom hook.

Comment: This hook has nothing to do with Redux. It is from the package `immer` and wraps around the `useReducer` hook, which let's you use reducers with component-local state, without any Redux store. It will not interact with your Redux store. With Redux, please don't use connect, but `useSelector` and `useDispatch`. Please read the official tutorial I linked above.

Comment: Please see upd 1

Comment: I repeat myself: whatever you will do with `useImmerReducer` or `useReducer` will never have any interaction with a Redux store. It is a different tool for a different purpose that just accidentally has the word "reducer" in it.

Comment: Ok, so that's where I was lost. I was thinking that they still somehow communicate one with another. Thank you very much for pointing me to this.